# CarouFredsel Separator

Tags: jquery, css, scroller, caroufredsel

I am trying to add a separator to a CarouFredsel scroller. The easiest way of doing it is by adding a right border to each one of the items, but has you can see there is a bug in the last item. Any good idea of how can I do this? The problem is that the calculations from the plugin won't allow me to correct this via margin or padding or even overflow. 
Here you can see the **[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ignaciocorreia/dcE6T/6/)**

I have tried:

```
#carouFredSel li {
    display: block;
    border-right: solid 1px black;
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
}
```

### Here is the result

I had to change the border separator form the Items to the Items -> link, here is the result [the result.](http://jsfiddle.net/ignaciocorreia/dcE6T/8/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think adding width to your first jsfiddle will solve the problem 
http://jsfiddle.net/dcE6T/15/

```
var pager = $("#carouFredSel").carouFredSel({

        items: 6,
        width:600,

        auto: false,
```

Comment: It may but I have 2 carousels in the same page and it has to be responsive. Thanks anyway.

Comment: if you copy paste same code with different carousal name; & different button names should work i guess..!!?

Comment: What I mean by responsive is that it is -> width:100% , so the fixed width won't work.

Comment: is it necessary width has to be 100%? or  can add width 90% or something similar?

Comment: Nice one. Have to try that one. :D

Comment: there is other way round too.wait ill give a try n let u know if succeeds

Comment: check this jsfiddle.net/dcE6T/27 if that's what you looking for. or u can put onafter event in previous and next button .let me know if u need help

Comment: I have tried that but if you want to do that you need to SCROLL also by 6 items, because if you scroll only 1 the thumbnail without border will be shown in the middle. Try to scroll to the right you will know what I am talking about